# Move a photo from one album to another

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

I checked through the api's but I may have missed it, if it exists... I can't find a write/modify api call to change move a photo from one user album to another (such as can be done  via FB's web interface by editing the album and use the pull down for each image to move them one by one.

Essentially I just want to modify for an image the enclosing album id.  I don't want to download from one album and upload to another as I want all the tags and comments to remain intact (as well as the photo's id)....

My goal is to create a simple app to be able to move all (or a selection) of photos from one album to another, ie. "merge albums" since FB's web interface does not have that functionality.  I have a ton of albums I created in 2009 when the limit was 60 photos per album so now that the limit is 200 I want to reduce my album count by over 67%...

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to remove photos, so effectively all you can do via the API is copy, you'd then have to remove the extraneous albums manually using Facebook's web interface

Comment: so no "move" as there is in the web ui :(